# Reactjs : how to reduce the array of objects to get the sum

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules, group

I have the array of objects and I want to group by description with the sum of credit. I tried with my code, but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

My Code:

```
var result1=[]
   entries.reduce((res, value) => {
       if (!res[value.description]) {
           res[value.description] = {description: value.description, credit: 0}
           result1.push(res[value.description])
       }
       
       res[value.description].credit= (parseFloat(value.credit) +
       parseFloat(res[value.description].credit)).toFixed(2)
      
       return res
      
   }, {});


   let analysisByDescStr = result1.map((str) => (
        <div>
            {str.description|| ""} =
            {str.credit|| ""}
        </div>
    ));
```

Array pf objects:

```
{description: 'GOOGLE *Google', credit: '1.99', category: 'TELECOM'}
{description: 'AMZN Mktp #0998', credit: '20.65', category: 'MERCHANDISE'}
{description: 'AMZN Mktp #06778', credit: '70.68', category: 'MERCHANDISE'}
{description: 'OLIVE YOUNG', credit: '60.03', category: 'MERCHANDISE'}
{description: 'SAFEWAY #0982', credit: '22.97', category: 'GROCERY'}
{description: 'PEET'S #11702', credit: '7.05', category: 'COFFEE'}
{description: 'SAFEWAY #0983', credit: '20.00', category: 'GROCERY'}
{description: 'AMZN Mktp #0234', credit: '-18.62', category: 'MERCHANDISE'}
```

My Expected Result :

```
AMZN Mktp=72.71
GOOGLE *Google=1.99
OLIVE YOUNG=60.03
PEET'S=7.05
SAFEWAY=42.97
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and apply whatever transformation you need to your `item.description` to match your expected labels

```
const result = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const label = item.description.substring(0, 7);
  return {
    ...acc,
    [label]: (acc[label] ?? 0) + Number(item.credit)
  }
}, {})
```

Comment: Not all the description is defined by "#", so I need to take the first 7 characters. thanks for the help though.

Comment: So you can do exactly the same excpet substring instead of split :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `substring`

Comment: Thanks! I solved it when I read the file use substring similiar to your solution.